# How to check the Role from the incoming request in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security

We have a spring boot application and there are 2 ldap groups (group 1 and group 2). Few application ID's are part of group 1 and few are part of group 2. In our spring boot application, we are checking whether the application ID's are part of any one of the ldap group using 'hasAnyRole(group 1, group 2)' in configuration class.

Inside getRoleDetails() method, we want to check the role from the incoming request and based on the role - call two different methods. How do we achieve this??

```
public class HelperClass implements HelperInterface{

private void getRoleDetails() {
//code to check the user role
}
}
```

Comment: Please suggest on this

Comment: Should be in `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthorities()` which return a list of `GrantedAuthority`which has a `getAuthority()` method that should return a string with role name.

Comment: `HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)` `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();`
`if(request.isUserInRole(Role_Name)){`
`// call method 1`
`}`

`else if(request.isUserInRole(Role_Name)){`
`// call method 2
`}`

If i use this approach, will it work??

Answer (score 0):

For us with Jumpcloud and rundeck the previous config didn't work.

We have to put this one

```
multiauth {
    com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule sufficient
        debug="true"
        contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
        providerUrl="xxxxxxx"
        bindDn="uid=xxxxx,ou=Users,o=xxxxxx,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
        bindPassword="xxxxxxx"
        authenticationMethod="simple"
        forceBindingLogin="true"
        userBaseDn="ou=Users,o=xxxxxxx,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
        userRdnAttribute="uid"
        userIdAttribute="uid"
        userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
        userObjectClass="inetOrgPerson"
        userLastNameAttribute="sn"
        userFirstNameAttribute="givenName"
        userEmailAttribute="mail"
        roleBaseDn="ou=Users,o=xxxxxx,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
        roleNameAttribute="cn"
        roleMemberAttribute="member"
        roleObjectClass="groupOfNames"
        rolePrefix=""
        cacheDurationMillis="300000"
        reportStatistics="true"
        timeoutRead="10000"
        timeoutConnect="20000"
        nestedGroups="false";

    org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
        debug="true"
        file="/etc/rundeck/realm.properties";
};
```

The users groups are working as well on the rundeck

Enjoy !